# String compare using char

Tags: java, string, string-comparison

Is this code correct?

```
class Palindrome
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String original = "Dot is Got";

        int len = original.length();

        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            char[] a = charAt[i];
        }

        for (int j = len; j >= 0; j++) {
            char[] b = charAt[j];
        }

        if (a[] == b[]) {
            System.out.print("Palindrome");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No, it is not correct.

Comment: Is it compiling? When it runs, does it perform as you would expect? Please give us a few different input strings, expected results, and actual results.

Comment: I wanted a cookie. The code did not give me a cookie when I ran it. -1.

Comment: This would be better posted to the SE Code Review

Comment: what you try to do with that code?

Comment: @JeremyKato No, that page is for reviewing working code to provide improvements. This code here is as distant from working code as the earth from the sun.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that what you try to achieve is rather this:

```
String original = "Dot is Got";

int len = original.length();
char[] a = new char[len];
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    a[i] = original.charAt(i);
}
char[] b = new char[len];
for (int j = len - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
    b[len - 1 - j] = original.charAt(j);
}

if (Arrays.equals(a, b)) {
    System.out.print("Palindrome");
} else {
    System.out.print("Not a palindrome");
}
```

**Output:**

```
Not a palindrome
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code wont even compile.

```
for (int i= 0; i < len ; i++)
{    
    char[] a = charAt[i];
}

for (int j= len ; j>=0 ; j++)
{ 
   char[] b = charAt[j];    
}
```

Here you are not instantiation the array (a and b) with length 1 which will always keep overwriting moreover you are making local variable that cannot be accessed outside the loop.

You cannot compare arrays like

```
if (a[]==b[])
{
    System. out. print("Palindrome");
}
```

What you can to do is

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    String original = "Dot is Got";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(original);
    if(original.equals(sb.reverse().toString())) {
       System. out. print("Palindrome");
    } else {
       System. out. print("Not a palindrome");
    }
}
```

Refer to [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#reverse--) to understand reverse function.

If you still want to do it the way you are doing it then yo need to change your code to

```
public class Palindrome {
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        String original= "Dot is Got";
        int len = original.length();
        boolean palindrome = true;
        for (int i= 1; i <= len ; i++)
        {
            if( original.charAt(len-i) == original.charAt(i-i)) {
                continue;
            } else {
                palindrome = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(palindrome) {
            System.out.println("Palindrome");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not a Palindrome");
        }
    }
}
```